# Mod_ReWrite regex unknown variables count?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i store uploaded files at **/storage/**  this way

- `public-adam-luki-uploads-123783.jpg`
- `park-hanna-adel-propic-uploads-787689.jpg`

the '-' count *unknown* because it slice the pic description

i want my users to be able to access it as

- `http://site.com/public/adam/luki/uploads/123783.jpg`
- `http://site.com/park/hanna/adel/propic/uploads/787689.jpg`

i think it is the same problem here

[mod_rewrite with an unknown number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122022/mod-rewrite-with-an-unknown-number-of-variables)

but i can't do it because i'm new to mod_rewrite module

i hope you can help me guys with the right rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

The question you link to doesn't actually do what you are trying to do (although the principle is the same) what they do is convert the url to `GET` variables.

If all you want to do is convert `/` to `-` then you can use a simple rewrite rule that will run in a loop:

```
ReWriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
```

There are of course a few caveats to that...

Firstly, even if you are trying to get to a real directory/file the rule will still switch out `/` and `-` and leave you with a 404. You can get around that by adding conditions; to stop it rewriting real files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You would do better however to limit the matches to only images (`jpg`s):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.jpg$ $1-$2.jpg [L]
```

### Preferred Solution

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteRule ^images/(.*)/(.*)uploads[-/](\d+)\.jpg$ images/$1-$2uploads-$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ReWriteRule ^images/(.*)$ storage/$1 [L]
```

This solution requires you to use urls like:

```
http://site.com/images/park/hanna/adel/propic/uploads/787689.jpg
```

The pseudo directory `images` means you can be *sure* that the url is actually one that you want to redirect and it doesn't break other images/links on your site.

The above rules take a url (like the example above) and transforms it like so:

```
images/park/hanna/adel/propic/uploads/787689.jpg    <--- Original
images/park-hanna/adel/propic/uploads-787689.jpg
images/park-hanna-adel/propic/uploads-787689.jpg
images/park-hanna-adel-propic/uploads-787689.jpg
images/park-hanna-adel-propic-uploads-787689.jpg
storage/park-hanna-adel-propic-uploads-787689.jpg   <--- Final
```