# passing variables in url without using $_GET method

Tags: php, variables, url, get

i want send my variables like this:

```
ExampleSite/var1/var2/var3/...
```

instead of this:

```
ExampleSite/?ex1=var1&ex2=var2&ex3=var3&...
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: i do search and i don't now what should i write, are you ok ?

Comment: You should read about `.htaccess` rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is poorly constructed, but I guess you need the apache `RewriteEngine`, i.e.:

Create a file named `.htaccess` on the root of your website and add the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /some_page?ex1=$1&ex2=$2&ex3=$3 [L]
```

Comment: tnx, but what is important is infinite variables

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122022/mod-rewrite-with-an-unknown-number-of-variables